# Primeiro elemento array de um array multidimensional como chave para os demais

Tags: php

Estou lendo uma planilha de Excel que me retorna um resultado como o abaixo, sendo o primeiro array o nome das colunas

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => nome
            [1] => sobre_nome
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => nome1
            [1] => snome1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => nome2
            [1] => snome2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => nome3
            [1] => snome3
        )

)
```

Existe alguma forma prática de usar o primeiro elemento array, que é sempre o mesmo, como chave para os demais arrays? ficando dessa forma:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nome] => nome1
            [sobre_nome] => snome1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nome] => nome2
            [sobre_nome] => snome2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nome] => nome3
            [sobre_nome] => snome3
        )

)
```

Comment: Também seria bom colocar como você esta criando este array, pois seria mais pratico já retornar o array como deseja ao invés de percorrer todo e criar outro array.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, basta você recuperar o primeiro elemento:

```
$chaves = $retorno[0];
```

depois percorrer o array começando do primeiro índice e adicionar ao novo array:

```
$novo = [];
for($i=1; $i < count($retorno); $i++){
  $novo[] = [
    $chaves[0] => $retorno[$i][0],
    $chaves[1] => $retorno[$i][1]
  ];
}
```

você terá o retorno desejado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nome] => nome1
            [sobre_nome] => snome1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nome] => nome2
            [sobre_nome] => snome2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nome] => nome3
            [sobre_nome] => snome3
        )

)
```

Veja [funcionando em ideone.com](https://ideone.com/izQdTg)